# Scala/Play - Building an aggregated JSON by getting partial data from the list

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick

I have a following case class:

```
case class Vehicle( type:String, brand: String, transmission: String)
```

I am using Slick to query a database that contains all of the columns in the case class and I get a query result like this (a list of objects):

```
List(Vehicle(car, audi, automatic), Vehicle(truck, toyota, automatic), Vehicle(motorcycle, bmw, manual))
```

I want the result JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "vehicles" : [
        {
            "type"          : "car",
            "brand"         : "audi",
            "transmission"  : "automatic",
        },
        {
            "type"          : "truck",
            "brand"         : "toyota",
            "transmission"  : "automatic",
        },
        {
            "type"          : "motorcycle",
            "brand"         : "bmw",
            "transmission"  : "manual",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now to achieve that, I can easily use a mutable list and map my DB result one by one and build out a JSON like that. Since I am already using the Play Framework, writing out JSON is a piece of cake. But, I would like to do things in a more functional way and without using any mutable variables.

How do I read the List of objects from the DB result and put it together like in the result JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define Json Format for Vehicle and then you can convert `List[Vehicle]` to Json automatically by `Json.toJson(vehicles)`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Vehicle( type:String, brand: String, transmission: String)

object Vehicle {
  implicit val vehicleFormat = Json.format[Vehicle]
}

//this will be slick function which gets data from database
def getVehiclesFromDB: Future[List[Vehicle]] = Future(List(Vehicle("a", "b", "c"), Vehicle("d", "e", "f")))
```

Inside the Controller

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (vehiclesRepo: VehiclesRepo) extends Controller {
  def getVehicles = Action.async { 
    vehiclesRepo.getVehiclesFromDB.map { vehicles =>
     Ok(Json.toJson(vehicles))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By defining that object Vehicle, `Vehicles.tupled` on the slick `override def *` does not resolve anymore.

Comment: @summerNight use `(Vehicle.apply _).tupled` instead

Comment: I have it like this: `override def * = (type,brand, transmission) <> (Vehicle.tupled, Vehicle.unapply)` which does not work and I tried `override def * = (type,brand, transmission) <> (Vehicle.apply _).tupled` as well.

Comment: @summerNight use this `override def * = (type,brand, transmission) <> ((Vehicle.apply _).tupled, Vehicle.unapply)` .. You missed Vehicle.unapply there